# Is there a method for estimating the solution set for a noisy system of polynomial equations?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, estimation, numerical-optimization

I have a system of polynomial equations with some equations of order 2 or higher. The coefficients are noisy, so they are random variable with some mean and covariance.

The system has multiple solutions (because it is nonlinear), and I want to solve for the entire solution set.

For example, I could use nonlinear least squares, but this would only give me one of the solutions. I want to estimate the entire solution set. Note that the fact the system is noisy makes it more difficult to estimate each solution.

For example, a single second order polynomial can be solved exactly (using the quadratic equation), but if the coefficients are noisy, the discriminant may be negative.

I can't find any information on this topic. Perhaps, I am not searching the right keywords.

Edit: I edited the question to clarify. Hopefully, this is more clear.

Comment: I presume you want to find the distribution of $x$ given that the coefficients are random variables. Monte Carlo simulation springs to mind?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you mean by "the coefficients are noisy" and "the entire solution set", and whether the two are supposed to be related? The system $(x+y)^2=1,(x-y)^2=1$ has more than one solution even though the coefficients are exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.

Take the case of a single variable rather than a system of polynomial equations. Small changes in the coefficients lead to large changes in the zeros; this is easily demonstrated using [Wilkinson's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial).

The situation will not improve in the multivariate polynomial case, and since your coefficients are noisy, your solution set will be entirely garbage.

Sorry man!

Comment: Nevertheless, all might not be totally lost.   There **are** situations where one can control the location of a zero despite small changes in the coefficients.

Comment: Wow. This is very unfortunate.

Comment: Note Robert Israel's comment. You might look to defining a condition number for your system and using it to see if there's hope to find a reasonable solution set.

Comment: Even if it is poorly conditioned, how do I go about finding every solution and not just a single solution.

Comment: This is the only method I have heard of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis; I have no experience with it so good luck!